# how to preview a single image on the table where i have looping data from the backend inside the react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preview

I have been trying to preview the image on the table inside the cell using src but if i preview it the image will preview on all the cell.
how to preview the image i have uploaded only inside the table cell where the data is coming from the backend.

```js
      if (e.target.files && e.target.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => {
      this.setState({ file: e.target.result });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      }
```

```js
<Table.Cell textAlign="center">
  <div>
    <img
      src={
        el.FPHOTOPATH !== ""
          ? this.state.photo + this.props.univcode + "/" + el.FPHOTOPATH
          : this.state.file
      }
      alt="Picture Not Found"
      style={{ height: "80px", width: "80px" }}
    />
    <input
      type="file"
      name="file"
      accept=" image/jpg, image/jpeg"
      onChange={(e) => this.onFileChange(e, el.FREGNO)}
    />
    <button onClick={() => this.onFileUpload(i, el.FREGNO)}>Upload</button>
  </div>
</Table.Cell>;
```